# Azure Managed instance can't create or restore DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

Edit: I am using SSMS 17.9

I created an Azure Managed Instance and am having a few issues with it. I am able to connect to it through SSMS but when I navigate and try to expand the Databases folder I get this error:

[image]

So I tried to create a DB on it (right click -> new db) and I get the following error:

[image]

Lastly I tried to backup and restore a test databased to the managed instance following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-get-started-restore

The restore was successful and in SSMS I can connect to the Managed Instance I made and in the browse it can see the DB I made but when I navigate to the folder structure to expand I get the first error again.

In conclusion:
- Does MI allow the user to create a DB right on it
- Why am I getting the error when I try to navigate the server to the DB I restored?

Comment: What version of SSMS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm using the latest I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue with SSMS and the only way to interface with the MI is through T-SQL.

I will update this answer once resolved in SSMS.

Comment: Confirmed...I receive an error as well when creating a database through SSMS 17.9, but doing a `CREATE DATABASE TestDB` works fine for me.